# Assistance with MS Access database and Vb.net Interface connection

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am trying to make a project using MS Access database to take info from interface into database. It does not connect to the database.

[This is what I get when I try to populate the database from the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxNsq.jpg)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred
> in System.Data.dIl

This is the coding I am using:

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub FrmStudentReg_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Student_List.accdb"
    
    'Me.Student_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Student_ListDataSet.Student_Details)
End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that you have no badges shows that you didn't take the site tour when prompted. Please do so and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works. You need to ask ONE SPECIFIC QUESTION only. If you can't connect to your database then that should be your question and the rest is irrelevant at this time. You should be providing code and information that is relevant to that one issue only. Once that is addressed, you can post another question for another issue if there is one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As mentioned by @jmcilhinney please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read also [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the connection issue, which is the first question and so the only one that should be addressed here, you are using the wrong provider. The Jet provider only supports old Office formats, which means MDB files for Access. For ACCDB files, you need to use the ACE provider. Unlike Jet, it is not part of Windows, so it needs to be installed. It will be installed as part of Microsoft Office or you can install it as a standalone component. It will need to be installed on every machine you want to run your app on. If that might be a problem, use an MDB file instead.